# julia, sparsearrays, CSC format

Tags: julia, slice, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to create a sparse matrix directly in csc format. this is because i can re-use the arrays I write, preallocating them and making @view in them.

Howevere if I use @view it gives an error, while if i leave the simple slicing, it works.

```
N::Int32 = 4
m::Int32 = 2
nzval_Sz = Array{Int8}(undef, N)
nzval_Sz[1] = 1
nzval_Sz[2] = -1
rowval_Sz = Array{Int32}(undef, N)
rowval_Sz[1] = 1
rowval_Sz[2] = 2
colptr_Sz = Array{Int32}(undef, N+1)
colptr_Sz[1] = 1
colptr_Sz[2] = 2
colptr_Sz[3] = 3 #last one is tot_nnz+1

sparsematrix = SparseMatrixCSC(m, m, colptr_Sz[1:m+1], rowval_Sz[1:m], nzval_Sz[1:m])
```

Am I sure it's not copying the data? (it's really important, as the preallocation is made cause i need to iterate with a lot of kronecker products and it will become a really large slicing, till it covers a really large matrix)

Comment: I don't think concepts like `view` and `preallocate` apply to sparse arrays.  `colptr` has to have one value per column + 1.  data and row indices will both have one value per nonzero entry.  If you want a slice of the first `m` columns, you'll have to look in `colptr` to determine how many non-zero entries there are in those `m` columns.  In the python sparse system, only the `lil` format has anything approximating a dense `view`.

Answer (score 2):

If you look how sparse arrays are implemented in Julia you will note that only `Vector`s are accepted (this is code from https://github.com/JuliaSparse/SparseArrays.jl/blob/main/src/sparsematrix.jl):

```
struct SparseMatrixCSC{Tv,Ti<:Integer} <: AbstractSparseMatrixCSC{Tv,Ti}
    m::Int                  # Number of rows
    n::Int                  # Number of columns
    colptr::Vector{Ti}      # Column i is in colptr[i]:(colptr[i+1]-1)
    rowval::Vector{Ti}      # Row indices of stored values
    nzval::Vector{Tv}       # Stored values, typically nonzeros
    ...
```

This means that at some point conversion to a `Vector` needs to occur.
The only nonallocating option is to `resize!` your vectors which can mean problems with reusability:

```
resize!(colptr_Sz, m) # non allocating
```

You could however easily make your own SparseMatrixCSC implementation. More or less something like:

```
struct FlexiSparseMatrixCSC{Tv, Ti<:Integer, Vi<:AbstractVector{Ti}, Vv<:AbstractVector{Tv}} <: SparseArrays.AbstractSparseMatrixCSC{Tv,Ti}
    m::Int                 
    n::Int                 
    colptr::Vi 
    rowval::Vi
    nzval::Vv
    ...
```

Now what basically you need to do is to copy most of the code from SparseArrays and this should work pretty well with the views.

Even faster would be to have a `ClippedSparseMatrixCSC` which would rather have an additional parameter just clipping the size (without using the views - just pass too large vectors)  but this would most likely require a bigger rewrite of the code.

In either case you should disallow all operations mutating your arrays implementations as I guess you wish to share the same data across many arrays.

Still another option could be having a huge sparse array and views over it differing on the size (depending on your application)